# Render WTF FieldList of SelectFields with Bootstrap

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

I would like to render a `flask_wtf` form with `bootstrap/wtf.html`.
The form contains a regular `SelectField` and a `FieldList` of SelectFields.
To render the single SelectField works fine using the function `wtf.form_field`.
However, applying the same function to each SelectField of the FieldList raises an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html", line 119, in template
    {{field.label(class="control-label")|safe}}
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My interpretation of the error is that the string "field.label" was called like a function using parentheses. On the other hand, the same seems to work for the single SelectField.

Here is form.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField, FieldList, FormField

class FormEntry(FlaskForm):
    selectfield = SelectField('Name', coerce=int)

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    selectfield = SelectField('Name', coerce=int, choices=[(2, "choice 2"), (1, "choice 1")])
    form_entries = FieldList(FormField(FormEntry))
```

And here is render.html:

```
 {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
 {% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
 {{ wtf.form_field(form.selectfield) }}
 {% for entry in form.form_entries %}
     {{ wtf.form_field(entry.selectfield) }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error source. 
In my script, I assigned the labels of the selectfields of `FormEntry` dynamically by

```
selectfield.label = "some_string"
```

However, the label of an `SelectField` is no a string but an object that contains a string variable `text`. Replacing the above line of code to

```
selectfield.label.text = "some_string"
```

did the job.